# Windows partition won’t boot despite being detected everywhere else

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

I recently removed a dual-booted OS from my computer. However, Windows won’t boot with the `IO1_INITIALIZATION_FAILED` error. Notes:

- the recovery partition boots fine
- `DISKPART` outputs:

> there are no fixed disks to show

- the partition’s filesystem can be accessed and read by other operating systems with no problems (Porteus running on a USB)
- running `BOOTREC` commands are ineffective.
- automatic repair and startup repair don’t work.
- system restore says i haven’t selected an operating system.
- system image recovery spits out `STATUS_WAIT_2 (0x80070002)`
- I even reseated the SSD. I’m just about out of ideas at this point.

Comment: If the OSes were properly installed in UEFI mode and you didn't delete the ESP (EFI System Partition) then Windows should boot. Before anything confirm the correct boot order in UEFI settings > Boot menu.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Windows Boot Manager is the default boot order. the only other entry is an old Fedora entry, which is worth mentioning because when i try to delete the entry in the BIOS it doesn’t save

Comment: The Windows has a problem indeed but unrelated with the dual-boot or the removal of Fedora. You may need to boot Windows installation media and repair it.

Comment: @ChanganAuto i tried everything listed in the question on both the recovery partition and external media.

Comment: If so reinstall Windows (you have the option to keep personal files). What else were you expecting? There's almost nothing about the error you reported: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x69--io1-initialization-failed

Comment: @ChanganAuto - In my experience you CANNOT perform an in-place repair of Windows outside of Windows, unless, you are willing to lose personal files and reinstall applications. If you choose the option to keep your files, you will basically told, you can’t do it from WinPE.

Comment: @Ramhound So you're saying that the installer won't recognize the installed Windows and offer that option? If that's the case then the OP must have backups and then reinstall from scratch, the currently installed Windows seems unsalvageable at this point.

Comment: @ChanganAuto - It will recognize the install, it will even show the option, but when selected it will give you an error message saying an upgrade cannot be performed by from an installation media.

Comment: @Ramhound if you say so I accept, you're the expert :) TBH, I NEVER needed to use such option so, my mistake.